# BFS Algorithm time complexity

Tags: time, complexity-theory

Can someone explain the time complexity of BFS algorithm O(V+E), if there is a for loop inside the while loop? I am solving the time complexity of BFS algorithm and I still didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the time complexity is O(V+E) is because as BFS goes through the graph, it marks the nodes as visited so it knows not to revisit them. Because each edge only has two endpoints, and each endpoint can only be visited once, the edge can only be observed at most twice. So, BFS never visits any "thing" more than twice (nodes, of which there are V many, it only can look at once, and edges, of which there are E many, can only be looked at twice). This means that T(V, E) < 2(V + E) which makes T(V, E) = O(V + E).